# How to add dependency using a method in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I can add a module dependency using either of

- **aar** dependency
- **local project module**
  Right now I am able to accomplish same using below

  ```
  if (foo(":awesomemodule")) {
      implementation 'com.example.app:awesomemodule:1.0'

  }
  else {
      implementation project(':awesomemodule')
  }
  ```

Now I want to repeat this code for multiple dependencies and want to create a method for same.

**I want something like this**

`customAddImplementation(':awesomemodule')`

```
ext.customAddImplementation = { moduleName ->
    if (foo(moduleName)) {
        return implmentation('com.example.app' + moduleName + ':1.0')
    } else {
        return project(path: moduleName)
    }
}
```

But this approach is not working, as `implementation()` definition is not found when i add my dependencies using `customAddImplementation(':awesomemodule')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
def customModulePath(String moduleName) {
    if (foo(moduleName)) {
        return "com.example.app:$moduleName:1.0")
    } else {
        return project(":$moduleName")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(customModulePath('awesomemodule'))
}
```

And bonus point: since the function doesn't try to add the custom module path to the implementation dependencies, but simply returns its path, you can ruse it to add dependencies to any other configuration.